# Azure Active Directory in .NET Core 2.2 Web-App | the signature is invalid / signature key was not found

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-2.2, msal.js

For an existing Angular & .NET Core 2.2 App I have configured an optional Microsoft Azure AD login, but the IIS server aways tells me that the token's signature is invalid.
This can be seen in a request to an API annotated with [Authorize]:

```
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The signature key was not found"
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The signature is invalid"
```

I have copied the exact token that was sent by the Microsoft-Server, after successfully logging into an organization Account.

These are the settings in the startup.cs file:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
           {
               options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
               options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
           }).AddJwtBearer("AzureAD", options =>
         {
            // Example: “https://login.microsoftonline.com/contoso.onmicrosoft.com”
            options.Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/"+Configuration["AzureADTenant"];
          
             options.Audience = Configuration["AzureADTenant"];
             options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

  //for testing, no difference to before
             options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
             {
                 ValidateIssuer = false,
                 ValidateAudience = false,
                 ValidateLifetime = false,
                 ValidateIssuerSigningKey = false,                    
             };

         })....;


  services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
           .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
           .AddAuthenticationSchemes("Default", "AzureAD")
           .Build();
        });
```

And here is the msalConfig:

```
export const msalConfig: Configuration = {
 auth: {
     clientId: 'my-client-id', // This is the ONLY mandatory field that you need to supply.
     authority: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/my-client-id/', // Defaults to "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common"
     redirectUri: '/', // Points to window.location.origin. You must register this URI on Azure portal/App Registration.
     postLogoutRedirectUri: '/', // Indicates the page to navigate after logout.
     navigateToLoginRequestUrl: true, // If "true", will navigate back to the original request location before processing the auth code response.
 },
 cache: {
     cacheLocation: BrowserCacheLocation.LocalStorage, // Configures cache location. "sessionStorage" is more secure, but "localStorage" gives you SSO between tabs.
     storeAuthStateInCookie: isIE, // Set this to "true" if you are having issues on IE11 or Edge
 },
 system: {
     loggerOptions: {
         loggerCallback(logLevel: LogLevel, message: string) {
             console.log(message);
         },
         logLevel: LogLevel.Verbose,
         piiLoggingEnabled: false
     }
 }
```

}

I tried several variations of the authority-URL but it showed no difference. The same values are configured in the frontend. Any ideas why the signature might be invalid?

Comment: What scope do you use in front-end? It should be one defined for your API in Expose an API tab of the app registration.

Comment: I don't think I defined any scopes specifically, at least I don't see any. It seems they are optional.

Comment: You have to define a scope to tell Azure AD what API you want to call. If you have for example "User.Read" there, you get a Microsoft Graph API token, which won't work on your API.

Comment: I didn't find any fields to set the scope in the msalConfig, also I'm not using Microsoft Graph API, the token simply needs to be validated by my web server so I can extract the email address.

Comment: It's specified in the call to loginRedirect / loginPopup / acquireTokenSilent / acquireTokenPopup / acquireTokenRedirect.

Comment: unfortunately I get the same error after settings the scope explicitly when calling acquireTokenPopup. Or do I have to set it on the server side too?

Comment: To debug the issue further, you should decode token at e.g. https://jwt.ms. Check that the audience ("aud") matches your API. Check the issuer ("iss") as well.

Comment: I tried decoding the token. the iss prop looks ok but the "aud" field is 00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000, which certainly ain't the value that I used.

Comment: Yeah, that's a Graph token.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure , you are providing correct values for audience and authority in start up class.

Audience must be Client Id of the app or some times app id uri according the application .

When you made a request for a token ,check if scope is  ["User.Read"]  which is for calling Microsoft graph.
As you need to call your api of the app , make sure to provide the scope for your web api exposed in the portal.

For that select the API permissions section in AAD portal for the app.

- Click the Add a permission button and make sure the it is granted consent in portal or later,

[image]

Before that we need to
Select the Expose an API section, and
Click **Set** next to the Application ID URI to generate a URI that is unique for this app (in the form of api://{clientId}).

- Select Add a scope
- Enter the  Scope name something like access_as_user

[image]

Make sure this scope is given in the frontend app .
See [msal auth-config.ts (github.com)](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-javascript-angular-tutorial/blob/main/3-Authorization-II/1-call-api/SPA/src/app/auth-config.ts)

Then retry and decode the obtained token in https://jwt.io  and see if issuer i.e `iss` value has v1 or v2 endpoint. Make sure `accessTokenAcceptedVersion` present in manifest in portal is `set to 2 if v2` is the endpoint.else null or 1 for v1 .
[image]
Also check if audience i.e; `aud` value is equal to `client id` which has to be.

**Reference:**

[msal call-api  (github.com)](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-javascript-angular-tutorial/tree/main/3-Authorization-II/1-call-api)